# Meteor command not found

Tags: meteor, command, prompt

I installed the same version from [Official Windows Meteor Support](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows) on one computer and the command "meteor" runs normally, now I tried to install in another computer but is giving me the issue that the "meteor command was not found". I tried to add the path to the system variables, but it doesn't seem to work. 
Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 20):

I have just discovered in Windows (I am using Windows 8.1) that you have to type meteor.bat to invoke meteor. e.g. ***meteor.bat create myapp***

Answer (score 16):

The answers already listed were only half the answer for me.

The following steps, resolved the issue.

Set the SYSTEM Environment Variable to:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\.meteor
```

Or if you prefer, change to your username explicitly

```
C:\Users\rich\AppData\Local\.meteor
```

Then as per the accepted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835752/meteor-in-git-shell-mingw/29842403#29842403) question.

Create a file named `meteor` in the directory where the meteor.bat is. E.g. the path above.

Hint, you can use

```
touch meteor
```

Copy these lines into the file and save

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd //c "$0.bat" "$@"
```

Comment: If you're using git bash or any other bash shell, this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Was trying to run meteor in a git bash shell on Windows 10 and this was the answer for me!

Answer (score 8):

For others that might come across this issue.

I'm on **Windows 10** and installed **Meteor 1.4**. Was getting `meteor command not found` when trying to run `meteor` from command prompt.

I checked my users PATH variables and found this entry:

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\.meteor\`

I removed the last backslash, saved the PATH variables, and then opened a new command prompt. The meteor command was now recognized.

My PATH variable entry now looks like this with the last backslash removed:

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\.meteor`

Note: You can replace `%username%` with your actual windows username. The entry should work fine as the system will resolve it to your username.

Answer (score 1):

If path variable is not present in environment variables, 
You can execute the command only from the directory where meteor is present. i.e., "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local.meteor\" directory.

To use the meteor from any directory inside the command prompt,
Add path variable to the environment settings.

"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local.meteor\meteor.bat".
Restart command prompt if already open.
This will enable meteor command to work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but it might help others who face similar issue.

I just installed meteor and had the same issue. It looks like it installed successfully and added C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local.meteor to the User variable (**not system variable**).

I am using Windows 10 and I might have to re-login or reboot for that to start working properly.

So, to use without re-login or reboot, use complete path in the directory where you want to create the project:

C:\Projects> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local.meteor\meteor my_project

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Node Command prompt instead of Terminal worked for me. Search for Node Command Prompt in the Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux**,
If  the problem comes from systemd service (systemclt) configuration, the PATH is not recognized properly, then:

Here is the error log:

```
Feb  3 00:13:43 localhost metassa-org[65870]: > meteor run --port=9999
Feb  3 00:13:43 localhost metassa-org[65881]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
Feb  3 00:13:43 localhost metassa-org[65870]: npm ERR! code 127
Feb  3 00:13:43 localhost metassa-org[65870]: npm ERR! path /var/www/domain.org/meteor/simple-todos-react
Feb  3 00:13:43 localhost metassa-org[65870]: npm ERR! command failed
```

Edit your service configuration file:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.meteor:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:$PATH"
```

Replace `/home/ubuntu` with your user folder containing meteor install.
You may replace all with your current $PATH value instead.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run start --prefix /var/www/meteor/simple-todos-react
```

Modify `/var/www/meteor/simple-todos-react` with your meteor project

Finally, restart your service.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```