# Meteor in Git Shell (mingw)

Tags: javascript, meteor, path, mingw

I am trying to do the tutorial for Meteor JS but I can't get it to work properly using the Git Shell that comes with Github for Windows. It can't find the meteor command.  It works in cmd and it is in the Windows environment path. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To run a `*.bat` command from MinGW's MSYS shell, you *must* redirect the execution to `cmd.exe`, thus:

```
cmd //c foo.bat [args ...]
```

The `foo.bat` command file *must* be in a directory within `$PATH`, (or you must specify the full path name ... using slashes, *not* backslashes unless you use *two* of them for each path name separator).  Also, note the double slash to inform `cmd.exe` that you are using its `/C` option, (since it doesn't accept the `-c` form preferred by the MSYS shell.

If you'd like to make the `foo.bat` file *directly* executable from the MSYS shell, you may create a two line Bourne shell wrapper script called simply `foo` alongside it, (in the same directory as `foo.bat`), thus:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd //c "$0.bat" "$@"
```

(so in your case, you'd create script file `meteor` alongside `meteor.bat`).

In fact, since this wrapper script is entirely generic, provided your file system supports hard file links, (as NTFS does for files on one single disk partition), you may create one wrapper script, and link it to as many command file names as you have `*.bat` files you'd like to invoke in this manner; (hint: use the MSYS `ln` command to link the files).

Comment: This works. Thank you for your help. Is there a way I can add something to my bash profile so the 'meteor' command works the same in MinGW as it does in cmd?

Comment: @Sean: there's no simple `profile` addition to do it, but you can create a simple wrapper script per `*.bat` file; see my expanded answer for details.

Comment: I created the script you mentioned and it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not using windows so I can't tell you the exact path, but you need to search for the path of the 'bin' folder (something like C:...\bin) where meteor is, and then add it to the PATH environment variable.

Or maybe it is better if you just install the windows version of meteor available here: https://win.meteor.com

Comment: I installed it with the windows installer and it's on the path. Just not working in the Git shell

Comment: Maybe the git shell is not loading the PATH variable. Try to call the executable meteor.exe with its absolute path.
Or just call the command with meteor.exe instead of meteor, with windows, anything is possible...

Comment: It appears there is no meteor.exe, just a meteor.bat and I am guessing that doesn't work the same on the path in MinGW as it does in cmd or powershell.

Comment: @Sean: if the executable for meteor is provided as a `.bat` file, then it's clearly intended that it should be run from `cmd.exe`.  MinGW's MSYS shell, (which I believe is what git for windows promotes), cannot run it *directly*, (it will run `.exe`s or Bourne shell scripts, but *not* `.bat` files). You can, however run it ` *indirectly*, as `cmd //c meteor ...` (assuming `meteor.bat` is in a directory within `$PATH`).