# installing meteor on windows 10

Tags: meteor

I've installed meteor through the official installer as the image shows:

[image: Meteor windows installer]

But the command is still not working on my terminal even when I restart the machine! The .meteor folder on my /users/$USER$ folder is non-existent. How can I install meteor under Windows 10?

Comment: I also ran into this issue, but I was able to find the installation directory at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.meteor`. Once I added that to my path, I was good to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is what I did.

I already had git installed on my computer for other reasons, but make sure you have git and 7z installed.  Additionally, and I don't know if it's because my migration to Windows 10 wasn't horribly successful, but make sure that 7z is in the path.   No need to reboot, just close the command window and reopen.  Type 'path' command and it should have the 7z at the end where you added it.

Once you're ready, get where you want to install meteor.  I just used my home directory, then type 'git clone http://github.com/meteor/meteor.git'

That will download the latest meteor from GitHub into a directory named meteor, once it's finished then you'll want to add that directory to your path as well.  Again, close the command prompt window and reopen and use the path command  to verify the path is there, and then start working on your new meteor projects.

Comment: But this will result in a checkout build, not a release build 1.1 or 1.2. Does anyone know how to install that?

Comment: You can clone a repository with a specific branch : `git clone -b release-1.2.1 http://github.com/meteor/meteor.git` or `git clone -b release-1.1 http://github.com/meteor/meteor.git`

Comment: be careful as you have to clone the repository recursively. use `git clone --recursive git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git`

Answer (score 16):

You need to open a command prompt with administrator privileges. So...

Start/Windows Icon > type "cmd" > right click on command prompt and choose "run as administrator" > Choose yes at the prompt > Now try "meteor" at the command prompt

Answer (score 3):

1. Run as administrator
2. If you go under `system32`, `cd` to `user/<your_name>`
3. `meteor create myapp`

I have done this on windows 10 and it's 100% working for me.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/alternate-windows-installation.md) has worked for me on Windows 10, after standard installer failed.

On some network or machine setups Meteor's installer for Windows may fail. In such cases, follow these simple steps to install Meteor manually.

Install 7-Zip or any other program that knows how to extract tar.gz    files. Download the installation archive from [here](https://packages.meteor.com/bootstrap-link?arch=os.windows.x86_32). In    a command prompt, run echo %LocalAppData%.meteor -- this is the    directory in which Meteor should be installed. Extract the    installation archive into the directory above. Add this directory to    your PATH environment variable. You should now be able to open a new    command prompt and run meteor. Some versions of Windows may require    restarting your machine first.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got the command to work.

The following steps, resolved the issue.

Set the **SYSTEM** Environment Variable to:

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\.meteor`

Or if you prefer, change to your username explicitly

`C:\Users\rich\AppData\Local\.meteor`

Then as per the accepted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835752/meteor-in-git-shell-mingw/29842403#29842403) question.

Create a file named meteor in the directory where the meteor.bat is. E.g. the path above.

Hint, you can use

`touch meteor`

Copy these lines into the file and save

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd //c "$0.bat" "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the new [2021 installer](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/npm-packages/meteor-installer/README.md) if you intend to install Meteor on Windows.